# Difficulty in understanding this summations to analyze time complexity

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, loops, java

I wanna know if what this link https://stackabuse.com/shell-sort-in-java/'s calculation of the complexity of shell sort is true.

Here's the shell sort algorithm:

```
void shellSort(int array[], int n){
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
      for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
        int temp = array[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap){
          array[j] = array[j - gap];
        }
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
}
```

Let me attach the site author's calculation using summations:

[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]
[image: 4th]
[image: 5th]
[image: 6th]

Where did he get the o(n log n) from? And why O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shellsort is *notoriously* difficult to analyze (surprising for such a simple algorithm). In Knuth's "Sorting and Searching" it gets an inordinate scrutiny, papers on its performance get published regularly.

Then again, the [Busy Beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) (At most how many ones does an $n$ state Turing machine write starting on an empty tape before halting?) is known only up to $n = 4$, the current record holder with 6 states writes $3.515×10^{18267}$ ones before halting...